# Save plots to variables without plotting them in the screen

Tags: r

I implemented the following function which return a list of cumulative plots representing data comparison between having specific condition (data1) compare to loosing the condition (data2)

```
  library("pryr")   
 myCumulativePlot <- function (data1,data2){
      for(x in 1:10){
        a%<a-% {
        plot(ecdf(data1[x,]),col="red",lwd = 2,verticals = TRUE, do.points = FALSE)
        legend("topleft",c("Enriched","Depleted"),lwd=c(2.5,2.5),col=c("red","blue"))
        lines(ecdf(data2[x,]),col="blue",xaxt='n',yaxt='n', ann=FALSE,lwd = 2,verticals = TRUE, do.points = FALSE)
        }
        myData[[x]]=a
    }
    return(myData)
    }
```

The function works as supposed to and the list contains all my Cumulative plots, However, it's very slow cause it also output the plots to the screen (the graphics window) though if I run the loop alone it doesn't plot to the screen (that's actually why I used "pryr" package in the first place).
All what I want is to cancel this ploting to screen while calling my function "myCumulativePlot", I know ggplot might be one solution but I need to use plot command cause I'm using "ecdf (cumulative distribution function)" command which only work with plot in R.
I also tried "recordPlot()" but it has the same problem when calling the function

Comment: Try wrapping the function with `invisible()` when calling it

Comment: `ggplot2` can ecdf.  http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_ecdf.html